# call a method from a class in php

Tags: php

This is kind of embarrassing but I having problems calling a method from a class in PHP, this is how it goes: I have created a class persona with its respectives properties, the code is

```
<?php
 class persona {
   private $id;
   private $nombre;        //varchar(50)
   private $correo;        //varchar(50)
   private $especialidad;  //varchar(50)
   private $nacionalidad;  //varchar(50)  
   private $sueldo;        //float
   private $isss;          //float 
   private $afp;           //float

   //getter
   public function getId() {
      return $this->id;
   }
   public function getNombre() {
      return $this->nombre;
   }
   public function getCorreo() {
      return $this->descripcion;
   }
   public function getEspecialidad(){
       return $this->especialidad;
   }
   public function getNacionalidad(){
       return $this->nacionalidad;
   }
   public function getSueldo(){
       return $this->sueldo;
   }
   public function getIsss(){
       return $this->isss;
   }
   public function getAfp(){
       return $this->afp;
   }

   //setter   
   public function setNombre($nombre) {
      $this->nombre = $nombre;
   }
   public function setCorreo($correo) {
      $this->correo = $correo;
   }
   public function setEspecialidad($especialidad){
       $this->especialidad=$especialidad;
   }
   public function setNacionalidad($nacionalidad){
       $this->nacionalidad=$nacionalidad;
   }
   public function setSueldo($sueldo){
       $this->sueldo=$sueldo;
   }
   public function setIsss($isss){
       $this->isss=$isss;
   }
   public function setAfp($afp){
       $this->afp=$afp;
   }

   public function __construct($nombre, $correo, $especialidad, $nacionalidad, $sueldo, $isss, $afp, $id=null) {
      $this->nombre = $nombre;
      $this->correo = $descipcion;
      $this->especialidad = $especialidad;
      $this->nacionalidad = $nacionalidad;
      $this->sueldo = $sueldo;
      $this ->isss = $isss;
      $this->afp = $afp;
      $this->id = $id;
   }

   public function mostrar(){
       $mensaje="hola";
       return $mensaje;
   }
 }
   ?>
```

as you can see at the end of the code I have created a function called mostrar, the only purpose of this is to show a message, now I want to call this method from a diferent class, my code is

```
<?php
require_once('persona.php');
class prueba{
    private $person;

    public function __construct(){
        $person= new persona("el nombre","el correo", "la especialidad", "la nacionalidad", "el sueldo", "el isss", "el afp");
        mostrando();
    }

  public function mostrando(){
      $person->mostrar();
  }
}
?>
```

but when I debug it doesn' show anything in the browser, I want to display the message from the class person.php, could you please tell me what is the problem in my code?

Comment: You didn't use an `echo` anywhere, so yeah, nothing is going to show in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable scope:

$person !== $this->person

```
class prueba{
    private $person;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->person= new persona("el nombre","el correo", "la especialidad", "la nacionalidad", "el sueldo", "el isss", "el afp");
        $this->mostrando();
    }

  public function mostrando(){
      echo $this->person->mostrar();
  }
}
```

`$this->person` is an object property, accessible from all methods in the class.

`$person` is a local variable, accessible only from the method/function in which it is defined (unless passed as an argument to other methods/functions)

Comment: You're not doing anything that will show the message.... see my edit, I've added an `echo` statement.... PHP will only generate output if you tell it to do so